# Javascript parsing from json format

Tags: javascript, json

Im having issue parsing javascript. I want to output the value of title permalink and the value of basename labeled "image_01". So it will only outputs `http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg`

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
var data={
   "items": [
      {
         "title": "HELLO THIS IS TITLE",
         "customFields": [
            {
               "basename": "image_01",
               "value": "<form mt:asset-id=\"352706\" class=\"mt-enclosure mt-enclosure-image\" style=\"display: inline;\"><a href=\"http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg\">201516.jpg<\/a><\/form>"
            },
            {  
               "basename":"image_02",
               "value":"<form mt:asset-id=\"352705\" class=\"mt-enclosure mt-enclosure-image\" style=\"display: inline;\"><a href=\"http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg\">201517.jpg<\/a><\/form>"
            },
            {  
               "basename":"image_03",
               "value":""
            },
         ],
         "permalink": "http://blog.com/index.php"
      }
   ]
}

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " + data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields[0].basename[0].image_01;
    </script>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/v57s2csa/3/**

Comment: you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/v57s2csa/6/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. basename is not any array so you cannot access using basename[0].
2. "image_01" is not any property.

so replace customFields[0].basename[0].image_01 with customFields[0].value property which has image path of basename labeled "image_01".

```
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " + data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Kanti has given right answer, you can be more specific:

```
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " + data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields[0].basename;
```